# Count all unique records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with the following format:

```
myTable
productgroupID | productID | views | date
1              | 10        | 25    | 2013-05-23 
4              | 105       | 15    | 2013-05-23 
7              | 60        | 65    | 2013-05-23
7              | 60        | 55    | 2013-05-22
7              | 60        | 45    | 2013-05-21
```

Now I want to sum all views  of a product in the moth May.
Result should be:

```
productgroupID | productID | viewed | month
7              | 60        | 165    | 2013-05-01
1              | 10        | 25     | 2013-05-01 
4              | 105       | 15     | 2013-05-01
```

I tried the query below, but this gives me all views of a specific productgroupID. But I need the sum of the unique productgroupID & productID.

`SELECT COUNT( views ) AS viewed, productgroupID FROM product_stats_daily GROUP BY productgroupID`

Comment: Can you create a `SELECT DISTINCT` subquery on `productID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the views totaled, then you can use the `sum()` aggregate function and then you can group by the `month` and `year` for the date:

```
select productGroupId,
  productId,
  sum(views) viewed,
  month(date) Month,
  year(date) Year
from myTable
group by productGroupId, productId, month(date), year(date);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00ffd/3)

You could also use `Date_Format` to get the date in the format that you want:

```
select productGroupId,
  productId,
  sum(views) viewed,
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') date
from myTable
group by productGroupId, productId, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00ffd/6)

Comment: Thanks! I can work with this! I realize now that I almost had it myself. I needed to change `COUNT()` into `SUM()` and adding , `productID` to the `GROUP BY`. Now I only need to add a `WHERE` to get all records from the previous month!

Comment: @Timo002 Sometimes you just need a little push! :) Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) will count number of rows while [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) will sum up value of retrieved rows.

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT SUM( views ) AS viewed, productgroupID
FROM product_stats_daily
GROUP BY productgroupID
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant way to force the date to the beginning of the month, but this should work:

```
SELECT
  ProductGroupID,
  ProductID,
  SUM(views) AS viewed,
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') AS Month
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
  ProductGroupID,
  ProductID,
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')
```